# onCompleted called early before processing RxJava concatMap

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, concatmap

I have two observables and used concatDelayError for sequential processing.

My problem is that onNext and onCompleted are called early before processing.
How do I know that all processing has been completed with concatDelayError?

Psudo code:

```
public Observable<Integer> concat(){
     int x = 10;
     int y = 20;


        Observable obx = Observable.create(emitter -> {
                    try {
                        int x = doSomeThing();
                        emitter.onNext(x);
                        emitter.onCompleted();
                    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                        emitter.onError(e);
                    }
                }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);   
        Observable oby = Observable.create(emitter -> {
                    try {
                        int y = doSomeThing();
                        emitter.onNext(y);
                        emitter.onCompleted();
                    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                        emitter.onError(e);
                    }
                }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);       
        Observable concated =  Observable.concatDelayError(ob1,ob2)
                 .compose(applySchedulers())
                 .replay().autoConnect();  

  }

    //somewhere else

    concat().subscribe(mReplaySubject);


    //somewhere else

     mReplaySubject.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            launchActivity(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            SplashActivity.this.finish();
                        }    
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }    
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Integer value) {

                        }
                    });
```

I am using reply() with autoConnect() and subscribing over ReplySubject as I need to share single subscription.

Comment: Are you sure your `Observer.onCompleted()` is called multiple times for a single subscription?

Comment: Pls add some logging by applying *.doOnEach()* to both source observables, and the concatenated one. Otherwise it is indeed unclear.

Comment: @akarnokd I am using ReplaySubject. I have changed the question. Can you please answer the question?

Comment: @akarnokd I logged onCompleted and it is not calling multiple times but it is calling early even before processing has been completed

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to `concated` directly without `ReplaySubject`? `replay().autoConnect()` does the caching for you already at that point.

Comment: @akarnokd won't it call doOnSubscribe() every time?

Comment: @akarnokd I want to do some processing when it subscribes only for first time, then how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide the full standalone code you have trouble with as the code you listed is inconsistent with your comments.

Comment: @akarnokd I have edited the question. I want to initialize this x and y on "only first time" subscription. How can I do that?

Comment: @akarnokd This is just an example of initializing. In actual I am clearing multiple arrays etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doOnSubscribe` before `replay().autoConnect()`, but you also need a way to make sure the returned `Observable` is set up at most once:

```
final class OnceObservable {

    final AtomicReference<Observable<Integer>> ref = new AtomicReference<>();

    int x;
    int y;

    Observable<Integer> concat() {
        Observable<Integer> obs = ref.get();
        if (obs != null) {
            return;
        }

        obs = Observable.concatDelayError(
            Observable.fromCallable(() -> doSomething()),
            Observable.fromCallable(() -> doSomethingElse())
        )
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
            x = 10;
            y = 20;
        })
        .replay().autoConnect();

        if (!ref.compareAndSet(null, obs)) {
            obs = ref.get();
        }
        return obs;
    }
}
```

Comment: One last question : Does  .replay().autoConnect();   automatically do caching of subscription?

Comment: still it is calling onCompleted() early

Comment: What subscription? Also how detect the early `onCompleted`?